# Find out the text element laid in a path in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I have some sort of interactive maps in my app. I have attached mouseover and mouseout handlers for each svg path. now I needed to place text over each svg path to identify the section.

All effect working fine but when user hover the text , which is laid on the path, the mouseover handler doesn't fire.

To cop this issue, I need to find out laid over text for the svg path, So I can attache same handler as the path itself.

This is my resolution towards this problem any other suggestion is also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you do not want the text to interfere with mouseover and mouseout handlers.  Try adding `style="pointer-events:none;"` to the text object.  Like so:

```
<text style="pointer-events:none;">Some Text</text>
```